# How to tackle different Image dimensions for classification

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-resizing

I am working on a problem where I have to classify images into different groups. I am a beginner and working with Keras with simple sequence model. How should I tackle the problem of images with different dimension in below code e.g. some images have dimension 2101583 while some have 210603 etc. Please suggest.

```py
model.add(Dense(100,input_dim = ?,activation= "sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(100,input_dim = ?,activation= "sigmoid"))
```

Comment: you'd have to make a choice on how to get them all into the same shape/dimensions.

Comment: If the answer met your requirements, please accept it. Otherwise please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple classification algorithms in Keras the input should always be the same size. Since Feedforward Neural Networks are consisting of an input layer, one to many hidden layers and one output layer, with all nodes connected, you should always have an Input at each Input-Node. Moreover, the shape and other hyperparameters of the Neural Network are static, so you can't change the number of inputs, and therefor the size for each Image in one Neural Network.

The best practice for your case would be to either downsize all Images to the size of your smallest Image, or upsize all Images to the size of your largest Image.

**Downsizing**
With downsizing you would actively delete pixels from your Image, including information contained in the pixels. This can lead to overfitting, but would decrease the computational time, too.

**Upsizing**
With upsizing you would add pixels to your image, without adding information. This would increase computational time, but you would keep the inforamtion of each Image.

For a good start I would suggest you to try and downsize your Images to the smallest one. This is a common practice in science as well [[1]](http://rogerioferis.com/VisualRecognitionAndSearch2014/material/papers/SuperVectorCVPR2011.pdf). One library to do so is [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/), for implementation issues, please refer to the multiple questions on Stackoverflow:

[Python - resize image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959262/python-resize-image)

[Opencv-Python-Resizing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060736/opencv-python-resizing-image)